# How to import data from excel sheet in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am working for a iOS project whose data source is an excel sheet. How can I convert the excel sheet to csv or plist?

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar issue recently. I saved my excel files to csv format, and then I downloaded the code described in this link:

http://blog.danilocampos.com/2009/12/04/convert-a-csv-into-a-plist-file/

which is for a mac app that converts csv files to plist files. I had to edit the

```
- (IBAction)executeConversion:(id)sender
```

method in AppController.m to get the plist in the format I wanted, but it was straightforward. It may not be the best solution, but it was the best I could find.

Comment: Thanks for your response,is there any possibility to convert the excel  sheet to csv programmatically within iphone sdk

Comment: Unfortunately not that I know of, I would be interested to find that out as well.